# How can you value_count combinations and not permutations?

Tags: python

I want to count the number of times two teams have faced each other.

```
data[['home_team','away_team']].value_counts()

home_team    away_team
Argentina    Uruguay      98
Uruguay      Argentina    81
Austria      Hungary      69
Hungary      Austria      68
Kenya        Uganda       66
                          ..
Philippines  India         1
             Hong Kong     1
Georgia      Romania       1
Philippines  Fiji          1
Abkhazia     Artsakh       1
```

As you can see Argentina and Uruguay for example are separated by their permutation. I want to count the combination such that Argentina and Uruguay for example will only occur once and the count will be 179 (98 + 81), and so on for other teams that have faced each other.

Comment: You should give us more info about the data structure because with the provided code, we can think different approaches which some of them are wrong or right. One way I could imagine, is with a set and a dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [`sort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) to have a consistent order, then use `value_counts`:

```
import numpy as np

out = (pd.DataFrame(np.sort(data[['home_team','away_team']]),
                    columns=['Team1', 'Team2'])
         .value_counts()
      )
```

Output:

```
Team1      Team2      
Argentina  Uruguay        179
Austria    Hungary        137
Kenya      Uganda          66
Abkhazia   Artsakh          1
Fiji       Philippines      1
Georgia    Romania          1
Hong Kong  Philippines      1
India      Philippines      1
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

Alternatively, using a `frozenset` (which is less efficient):

```
out = data[['home_team','away_team']].apply(frozenset, axis=1).value_counts()
```

Output:

```
(Argentina, Uruguay)        179
(Austria, Hungary)          137
(Kenya, Uganda)              66
(India, Philippines)          1
(Hong Kong, Philippines)      1
(Romania, Georgia)            1
(Fiji, Philippines)           1
(Abkhazia, Artsakh)           1
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

Just for fun, another approach with [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html), but much less efficient (unless you have most combinations in the input):

```
tmp = data.pivot_table(index='home_team', columns='away_team', aggfunc=len)
out = tmp.add(tmp.T, fill_value=0).stack()
```

Output:

```
Abkhazia     Artsakh          1.0
Argentina    Uruguay        179.0
Artsakh      Abkhazia         1.0
Austria      Hungary        137.0
Fiji         Philippines      1.0
Georgia      Romania          1.0
Hong Kong    Philippines      1.0
Hungary      Austria        137.0
India        Philippines      1.0
Kenya        Uganda          66.0
Philippines  Fiji             1.0
             Hong Kong        1.0
             India            1.0
Romania      Georgia          1.0
Uganda       Kenya           66.0
Uruguay      Argentina      179.0
dtype: float64
```